# some lines appear thick, others do not

Tags: tikz-pgf

using the following code only makes the lines surrounding the rectangle specified in the last 'draw' command line, the rest appear normal regardless of the attempt at making them thick

```
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}


 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[draw=gray, dashed, thick, ->] (4.125,-4) -- (4.125,4);
 \draw[dashed, very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
 \filldraw[thick , fill=gray, draw=black] (4,1) rectangle (4.25,3);
 \filldraw[thick , fill=gray, draw=black] (4,-0.5) rectangle (4.25,0.5);
 \filldraw[thick , fill=gray, draw=black] (4,-1) rectangle (4.25,-3);
 \filldraw[thick , fill=red, draw=black] (0,0.75) circle (0.1cm);
 \filldraw[thick , fill=blue, draw=black] (0,-0.75) circle (0.1cm);
 \draw[thick , ->] (0.1,0.75) -- (4.25,0.75);
 \draw[thick , ->] (0.1,-0.75) -- (4.25, -0.75);
 \filldraw[thick, draw=black, fill=gray] (8,-3) rectangle (8.25,3);


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be a viewer issue. Try different viewers and/or zoom in. With a high enough zoom you'll very likely see, that the line widths are correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because resolved in comments (viewer issue).

Answer (score 1):

I zoomed in and it worked, thanks guys